# Setting a SqlParameter and checking if it's null, ?? vs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, object, operators

Recently I learned you can check if a value is null when setting the value for a `SqlParameter` and if it's null set is a null. This was using the null-coalescing operator `??` which is very straight forward:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ID", ID.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Now can anyone explain this next example in more detail? Obviously, it's checking the string to see if it's empty but how does everything after the `?` operator work? Also what are the difference between `??` and `?` when it comes to performance?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ID", ID.Text == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : ID.Text));
```

Comment: Note that `ID.Text ??` will often do nothing if `ID` is a control (since most controls will return `""` rather than `null`).

Comment: Also, I'd suggest reading up on `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a 'help me read the manual' question

Comment: @mjwills `ID` was a textbox that often times return `""` and inserted in my db rather than null. Also yes, I could use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. I just didn't think of it, was focused on the right side of the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two different functions, one is for null coalescing while the other is acting as a conditional operator for a ternary function.  The Microsoft Developer Network explains the two as [follows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).

> Null-coalescing Operator This operator has higher precedence than the
>   next section and lower precedence than the previous section.
>
> x ?? y – returns x if it is non-null; otherwise, returns y.

---

> Conditional Operator This operator has higher precedence than the next
>   section and lower precedence than the previous section.
>
> t ? x : y – if test t evaluates to true, then evaluate and return x;
>   otherwise, evaluate and return y.

Comment: Clear easy explanation thank you. This may also help future viewers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator Just so happens I finally found it after I asked this.